# PHP socket_write in a loop on non-blocking socket only last write succeeds

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, stream, nonblocking

I want so send data over a socket to 2 different endpoints. This is for sending messages via WebSockets and Push-Services (a seperate worker instance does that).
As my application does not need an answer from the endpoint, I set the socket to non-blocking so my applications finishes request fast.

The problem is, that only the last socket_write is done. The first endpoint does not receive data.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($workerInstances as $workerInstance) {
  // $workerInstance contains a hostname

  $sock=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
  socket_set_nonblock($sock);

  $connRes = socket_connect($sock, $workerInstance, 8018);
  if ($connRes) {
    $written = socket_write($sock, $data,strlen($data));
    socket_close($sock);

    if ($written === FALSE) {
      $result[] = $workerInstance . ': Connected but failed to write';
      ++$failures;
    } else {
      $result[] = $workerInstance . ': OK - ' . $written . ' bytes written';
    }

  } else {
    ++$failures;
    $result[]=$workerInstance . ': Failed';
  }
}
```

$result is then:

```
[
    "app01.local: Connected but failed to write",
    "app02.local: OK - 63 bytes written"
]
```

I think the return of socket_write in non-blocking mode is not reliable, right? But the first endpoint really receives no data. In blocking mode, both endpoint get their data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php#84465

In non-blocking mode I have to wait until socket connection has finished before writing to the socket. Therefore we do the connect in a loop until the result is not FALSE or the error is any other than "Connection in progress" (or we waited long enough for connection to be established).

```
foreach ($workerInstances as $workerInstance) {
  $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
  socket_set_nonblock($sock);

  // wait until connection established
  $attempts = 30;
  while (!($connRes = socket_connect($sock, $workerInstance,
      8018)) && $attempts) {
    $error = socket_last_error();
    if ($error != SOCKET_EINPROGRESS && $error != SOCKET_EALREADY) {
      $result[] = $workerInstance . ' Socket connect error: ' . socket_strerror($error);
      break;
    } else {
      $result[] = $workerInstance . ' Connecting...';
    }

    usleep(1000);
    --$attempts;
  }


  if ($connRes) {
     $written = socket_write($sock, $data,strlen($data));

     if ($written === FALSE) {
        $result[] = $workerInstance . ': Connected but failed to write';
        ++$failures;
     } else {
        $result[] = $workerInstance . ': OK - ' . $written . ' bytes written';
     }

  } elseif ($attempts === 0) {
    ++$failures;
    $result[]=$workerInstance . ': Failed - Timeout!';

  } else {
    ++$failures;
    $result[]=$workerInstance . ': Failed';
  }
  socket_close($sock);
}
```

Now the $result is

```
[
    "app01.local Connecting...",
    "app01.local: OK - 63 bytes written",
    "app02.local Connecting...",
    "app02.local: OK - 63 bytes written",
]
```

Comment: Why not put `socket_set_nonblock($sock):` after you have opened the connection?